# calling ffmpeg.exe in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg

I am just a newbie to c++. 
I'm trying to use FFmpeg in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2012, by calling the ffmpeg.exe file inside it.

This is what I tried so far:

```
//FFMPEG CALLING
char ffmpeg2[BUFSIZ];
strcpy(ffmpeg2,"..\bin\ffmpeg.exe");
strcat(ffmpeg2,"-f s16le -ar 8K -ac -ss");
strcat(ffmpeg2,buffers);    //string hh:mm:ss
strcat(ffmpeg2,"-t");
strcat (ffmpeg2,buffer);    //string hh:mm:ss
strcat(ffmpeg2,"-i ..\\rec.pcm ..\Desktop\newFolder\filename");
if(system(ffmpeg2) !=0) 
{
    ft =fopen("ffmpeg_err.txt","a");
    fprintf( ft,"my command failed...\n" );
    fclose(ft);
}
else
{system(ffmpeg2);}
```

It keep producing the my command fail in the text file.
Do you guys have any hint on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not adding any **spaces** before or after calling strcat so your final command would be something like
`..\bin\ffmpeg.exe-f s16le -ar 8K -ac -ss<buffers>-i ..\\rec.pcm ..\Desktop\newFolder\filename`
add a space after ffmpeg.exe, after -ss, before -t and before -i so your 
final command will become
`..\bin\ffmpeg.exe-f s16le -ar 8K -ac -ss <buffers> -i ..\\rec.pcm ..\Desktop\newFolder\filename`

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It seems to read in the starting time and duration when I try writing to text file to see the output.

Comment: Accept my answer if it has solved your problem. If there is any other problem in your code then kindly elaborate it.